# How can I add specific colors by levels to nodes? (R-collapsibleTree package)

Tags: r, collapsibletree-r

How can I add specific colors by levels "Manager" and "Operator" to nodes ?
(#3452FF and #FFC900)

I tried

```
   org$Color <- org$Title
    levels(org$Color) <- c("#3452FF", "#FFC900")
```

without success...

```
                org <- data.frame(
      Manager = c(
        NA, "Ana", "Ana", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Claudette", "Claudette", "Danny",
        "Fred", "Fred", "Grace", "Larry", "Larry", "Nicholas", "Nicholas"
      ),
      Employee = c(
        "Ana", "Bill", "Larry", "Claudette", "Danny", "Erika", "Fred", "Grace",
        "Henri", "Ida", "Joaquin", "Kate", "Mindy", "Nicholas", "Odette", "Peter"
      ),
      Title = c(
        "President", "VP Operations", "VP Finance", "Director", "Director", "Scientist",
        "Manager", "Manager", "Manager", "Operator", "Operator", "Manager",
         "Manager", "Manager", "Operator", "Operator"
      )
    )


    org$Color <- org$Title


    levels(org$Color) <- c("#3452FF", "#FFC900")

    org$tooltip <- paste0(
      org$Employee,
      "<br>Title: ",
      org$Title,
      "<br><img src='https://source.unsplash.com/collection/385548/150x100'>"
    )

    collapsibleTreeNetwork(
      org,
      attribute = "Title",
      fill = "Color",
      nodeSize = "leafCount",
      tooltipHtml = "tooltip"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/collapsibleTree/versions/0.1.7/topics/collapsibleTreeNetwork) the `fill` parameter is:

> either a single color or a column name with the color for each node

This means `Color` column needs to have one color per row.

#### Mapping one color per job title

One way to map color to job title to create a `factor` (which I think you were getting at with your use of `levels()`). I'll use the [Set1](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/the-a-z-of-rcolorbrewer-palette/) palette from `RColorBrewer` for this example.

```r
org$Color  <- factor(
    org$Title,
    levels = unique(org$Title),
    labels = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(unique(org$Title)), "Set1")
)
```

This maps one color to each title as follows:

```r
#      Color         Title
#     <fctr>        <char>
# 1: #E41A1C     President
# 2: #377EB8 VP Operations
# 3: #4DAF4A    VP Finance
# 4: #984EA3      Director
# 5: #FF7F00     Scientist
# 6: #FFFF33       Manager
# 7: #A65628      Operator
```

Then you can draw the plot in the same way:

```r
collapsibleTreeNetwork(
      org,
      attribute = "Title",
      fill = "Color",
      nodeSize = "leafCount",
      tooltipHtml = "tooltip"
    )
```

[image]

#### Mapping just the Manager and Operator titles

Alternatively, it is not necessary to create a `factor`, so to just set the Manager and Operator colors and leave all others `NA` (which seems to be white by default), you can just assign the relevant color codes to the `Color` column.

```r
org <- within(org, {
    Color  <- NA
    Color[Title == "Manager"] <- "#3452FF"
    Color[Title == "Operator"] <- "#FFC900"
})
# use the same code to draw the plot
```

[image]

Comment: not working with my real data. Color need to be a factor type ?

Comment: @Wilcar it's difficult to say why it's not working as I don't know what your real data looks like. Perhaps you can post a different question with your real data, or data which is similar enough to it that it also triggers the same error?